# Is GlassFish Server having any relation with Java EE SDK

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

As for obtaining Glassfish server we have download Java EE SDk. Is there any co-relation of GlassFish server and Java EE SDK. 
Did we need to download the same for JBoss and Apache Tomcat

Comment: Nope. You need an application server of your interest to develop applications on Java EE platform anyway. You can download and install GlassFish and other servers separately. Apache Tomcat, on the other had, is a bare-bones Servlet container - not a Java EE complaint container.

Comment: When its important to have SDK even if we have JDK and application server for executing Java EE application

Comment: "*Important*"? Java EE SDK basically contains GlassFish Server, a bunch of documentations and optionally NetBeans IDE. It is absolutely not needed for Java EE. You can, if necessary, download them all separately.